# PHP - insert button to delete a row from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site/forum where you can post things. The users can posts on their personal wall. I want to put a delete button for every post in the wall. When i press it to detele the row in table that coresponds to that post. How can i do that?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $entity = Post::getTheThings($id);
    $entity->deleteMehhhhh();
```